# Are there any restful interfaces to git?

Tags: git, rest

I have been looking for a restful api to git and dont seem to find any. The closest thing i got is Github's api to access some repositories info.
Are there any other impelementations out there?

Comment: I know this a rather old question, but new things have come up since. Here is a RESTful interface to git data by Hulu:

http://tech.hulu.com/blog/2013/09/09/restfulgit-an-open-source-web-service-for-accessing-git-data/

https://github.com/hulu/restfulgit

Comment: @Ajeet I already mentioned  it my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Projects I've spotted:

1. [Gerrit](http://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/rest-api-projects.html) - has a REST server, Java
2. [Gandalf](https://gandalf.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#) - core is there, coupled to MongoDB, Python + Flask
3. [git-rest-api](https://www.npmjs.org/package/git-rest-api) NodeJS, very incomplete

Answer (score 7):

[Orion Git API](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Orion/Server_API/Git_API) Orion is an Eclipse project

[RESTFul Git](https://github.com/hulu/restfulgit) from Hulu on github

Answer (score 3):

git doesn't sport an http server so you need some middleware solution that can serve git repos via http. Githubs api does it and there are possibly other solutions out there.

Answer (score 1):

You can use gitlab and its REST api:
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/index.html