# Run Git commands in microservice

Tags: git, microservices, spring-cloud, jgit

I'm implementing microservice (in Spring Cloud) which acts as facade for Git operations invoked by UI layer. I'm trying to use jgit, but the problem is that it requires filesystem. So I have to clone remote repository to local filesystem. Problem is that then microservice is not stateless, and also other problems arises:

- cloning before every operation takes too much time so is not an option
- having multiple instances of such microservice can lead to different repositories (push take some time)
- commits on different nodes at the same time can lead to conflicts

I would like to treat Git repository in similar way to database, so all operations should be done without using filesystem, cloning etc. - just invoke command on remote and it's done.

I would like to add that it's quite hard to search for solution, because "Git microservice" phrase is quite common but in other sense (storing sources in repository).

Edit: I've just found
[Are there any restful interfaces to git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9442788/are-there-any-restful-interfaces-to-git)
but any other ideas would be nice

Comment: What kind of commands are invoked by the UI layer, and what does a façade mean in this context?

Comment: You say that you don't want to use a file filesystem, but that's at the core of what git does. What that means is that in your facade you're essentially going to fake the appearance of git but the underlying implementation you're going to have to build completely yourself.

Comment: At the end of the day, there's going to be a filesystem down there somewhere, because the data has to be stored somewhere.

Comment: *Git repository in similar way to database, so all operations should be done without using filesystem, cloning etc* this is basically the opposite of what GIT is designed to do. and it works this way for very good reasons (fault tolerance, distributed repo, backups, etc) My advice, don't try an alter GIT to suit you, alter your processes to suit GIT.

Comment: I want to invoke few simple commands like listing selected folder, adding/updating/removing file. Files are edited in UI and send via REST call. Just CRUD interface for GIT repository, but it should happen in microservice. Files to be edited are already in GIT repository so writing my own solution is not an option

Comment: Okay, but folders are part of filesystems. You said you don't want a filesystem.

Comment: Currently all files are committed at the root level, so only root folder of repository needs to be listed. In the future there can be need of much more sophisticated browser, like browsing remote FTP server, where folders exists. Similar approach can be seen when sending file from browser to FTP server - microservice can act as a middle layer receiving file and sending it to FTP server, using streams it can upload very big files without accessing filesystem on microservice

Answer (score 1):

Try Locked Working Copy from [scm4j API](https://github.com/scm4j/scm4j-vcs-api). It can create locked folder in shared network folder which can not be used by another microservices until release. Do any checkout and other work within Working Copy. Then it will be reused if the same repository url is provided so you need to execute just switch+pull, not clone. If another microservice is currently working with the Working Copy then another available will be taken and locked or new one will be created and locked and so on..

```
public static final String WORKSPACE_DIR = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir") + "scm4j-vcs-workspaces"; // or provide network shared folder path
public static void main(String[] args) {
    IVCSWorkspace workspace = new VCSWorkspace(WORKSPACE_DIR);
    String repoUrl = "https://github.com/scm4j/scm4j-vcs-api";
    IVCSRepositoryWorkspace repoWorkspace = workspace.getVCSRepositoryWorkspace(repoUrl);
    try (IVCSLockedWorkingCopy wc = repoWorkspace.getVCSLockedWorkingCopy()) {
        // wc.getFolder() is locked folder where you can do any checkouts. Another microservices can not use this folder
    }
    // here folder is unlocked and can be reused if the same repository url is provided
```

}

Comment: it still uses filesystem.
I've ended up with similar solution, just synchronized all methods working on this repo